# How to pass variable from blade to LARAVEL commands

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to pass user_id from blade to routes, and then use the variable into a laravel command. How can I do?

**lista_lavori.blade.php**

```
<div class="box-tools">
     <a href="/stampasingoloreport/{{$utente->id}}" class="btn btn-box-tool" role="button"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></a>
</div>
```

**web.php - route**

```
Route::get('/stampasingoloreport/{id}', function ($id) {
    Artisan::call('StampaSingoloReport:stampasingoloreport');
    return back();
});
```

**StampaSingoloReport.php - Commands**

```
public function handle()
{

    // static id i need to change this dinamically
    $id = 5;
    $utente = \App\User::where('id',$id)->get();

    //invio email per avvertire l'utente
    $data = array('utenti'=>$utente);
    Mail::send('mail.invioMailReportLavoriSingoli', $data, function($message) {
        $message->to('rubertocarmine94@gmail.com', 'Admin Risorse Umane') ->subject('Email da piattaforma BancaStatoHR') ;
        $message->from('rubertocarmine94@gmail.com') ;
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array to `call()` method like

```
Route::get('/stampasingoloreport/{id}', function ($id) {
    Artisan::call('StampaSingoloReport:stampasingoloreport',[
      'id' => $id     
 ]);
  return back();
});
```

Now in your `handle` method, you can access these arguments like

```
protected $signature = 'StampaSingoloReport:stampasingoloreport { id } ' ;

function handle(){
  $this->argument('id');
 // your code
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: levaral I got this error The "id" argument does not exist.

Comment: @CarmineRub  have you used the code which is provided in the answer?

Comment: levaral yes but don't work! Can you show me the href="" in the blade? please.

Comment: Artisan::call('StampaSingoloReport:stampasingoloreport',[
      'id' => $id     
 ]); this code will run the command with arguments

Comment: function handle(){
  $this->argument('id');
 // your code
}   this function will recieve the argument

Comment: @CarmineRub have a look at my comments

Comment: this code is good for send variable from blade to route? 
<a href="{{route('X', ['id'=> $utente->id]}}" class="btn btn-box-tool" role="button"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></a>

Comment: You are not using nameed route so use `url('/stampasingoloreport/'.$utente->id)`

Comment: i'm so sorry sir but don't work. I got the same error. The "id" argument does not exist.

Comment: remove this line from your handle function  ` $this->argument('id');`
`

Comment: @CarmineRub remove this line  ` $this->argument('id');` `

Comment: levaral I really do not know why he sends me this error. Removing this line gives me the same error. How it's possible? The url path it's correct with the correct value id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166442/discussion-between-laravel-levaral-and-carmine-rub).